# Rotate Array by k

Tags: java, arrays, logic

Given an array and a number k we have to rotate array k times.

```
Sample Input
1            //number of of testcases 
5 2          //5(array size) 2(K value)
1 2 3 4 5    /array elements
```

```
Sample output
4 5 1 2 3
```

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        // Write your code here
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int testcases=input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<testcases;i++)
        {
            int size=input.nextInt();
            int rotationNo=input.nextInt();
            rotateArray(size, rotationNo, input);
        }
    }
    public static void rotateArray(int size, int rotationNo, Scanner input)
    {
        int[] arr=new int[size];
        int[] result=new int[size];

        rotationNo=rotationNo%size;

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=input.nextInt();
        }

        int resultIndex=0;

        int index=size-rotationNo;

        int k=index,t=0,track=0;

        while(true)
        {
            if(k<size)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[k++]+" ");
                ++track;

                if(track==size)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(t<index)
            {
                if(t==(index-1))
                {
                    System.out.print(arr[t++]);
                }
                else
                {    
                    System.out.print(arr[t++]+" ");
                }
                ++track;
                
                if(track==size)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This question was asked in a programming competition. My all testcases were passing except one which showed time limit exceeded. But I am not understanding what is the cause of time limit exceed. Loops will always halt whatever be the testcase.
Time Complexity of my code is O(n).
Is there another better and efficient solution?

Comment: "*My all testcases were passing except one which showed time limit exceeded.*" - Please include the test case.

Comment: @Turing85 Test cases usually are secret in this kind of situation.

Comment: TLE does not mean that loops fail to end. It is not about endless loops. It is about efficiency.

Comment: The testcases were hidden. By the way efficiency of my code is O(n), so it must be about endless loops.

Comment: I guess the TLE test case looks like `1\n10000 1\n1 2 3 4 5 ...`. That eliminates programs which do too much storing.

Comment: ... and, more relevantly, shifting.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks That is valid input. Would you mind if I incoporate the modulo idea into my answer? I will mention your (cool - though hard to type) username of course. Or are you going to make an answer?

Comment: All O(N) solutions are not alike. They are also not always the most efficient solution.

Comment: Please elaborate this promble clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Start outputting the input directly (i.e. without storing it) as soon as k values have been read and stored.
Then output the k initially read and stored values.

The shifting inside the array, is the relevant operation here.
The fewer shifts are done (the distance of shifting is not really relevant here, if implemented correctly), the better. It includes the storing and retrieving to/from an array. I consider the reading and outputting, if done without any processing in between, to be negligible. I.e. I focus on the shifting.

Strictly speaking, the reading and outputting is processing and that would mean that no improvement of O() can be calculated.

But allow me to ignore the reading and outputting for an O() estimation of the improvement:

The proposed recommendation will improve the number of array-accesses during shifting from O(n) to O(k). Admittedly the reading and outputting is ignored here. Storing and retrieving from an array and especially the shifting inside the array is avoided here and that is the O(k) part which is relevant here.
So the relevant operations are O(k), ignoring n-k values in O(1).

A test case like

```
1
10000 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
```

will easily eliminate programs which after reading and before outputting, do `O(4*10000)`, i.e. store all, read and write all for shifting and then read all for outputting. Compared to `O(2*1)` for only storing a single value and reading again for outputting at the end.
*(Yes, I know clean O() analysis does not use factors, or any digits. You stil get the point, I hope. ;-)*

Here is a code proposal (simplified to a single testcase):

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testcases= input.nextInt(); //ignored, assuming 1
        int size     = input.nextInt();
        int rotation = input.nextInt();
        int i=0;

        int[] newArr = new int[rotation%size]; //small array
        // based on the nice idea by User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks
        
        for(; i<rotation%size; i++)
        {
            newArr[i] = input.nextInt(); // few write accesses
        }
        for(; i<size; i++)
        {
            System.out.println( input.nextInt()); //many direct outpots
        }
        for(i=0; i<rotation%size; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(newArr[i]); // few outputs from array
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

For an input of:

```
1
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

It gets you an output of:

```
3
4
5
1
2
```

Same output for a modulo-requiring input of:

```
1
5 7
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: "*That will improve from O(n) to O(k).*" - You cannot process `n` values in `O(k)` with `k < n`.

Comment: But I can ignore n-k  values in O(1). Admittedly the reading and outputting is ignored here. Storing and retrieving from an array and especially the shfting inside the array is avoided here and that is the O(k) part which is relevant here. @Turing85 Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You have to output those `n-k` "*ignored*" entries at the end.

Comment: I am ignoring n-k, reducing to k.

Comment: No, I have to output the k non-ignored values at the end. The n ignored values have already been output. And the whole shifting in the array is avoided completely....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219849/discussion-between-turing85-and-yunnosch).

Comment: I will edit, to define some assumptions of what is relevant operation here....

Comment: @Turing Done. Ping.

Comment: Why? Do you have trouble with implementing it? Or do you doubt the concept?

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a solution below which will directly output the scanner input up until the size of input has been met. It has a constant time o(n) for input, however it only touches each item once. and avoids the use of a while loop that may otherwise increase the multiplier of the iterations.

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rotation = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int size = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();


        int[] values = rotate(rotation, size, new Scanner(System.in));

        for(int i : values){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static int[] rotate(int rotation, int size, Scanner input){

        int[] newArr = new int[size];

        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){

            int newPosition = i + rotation;

            newPosition = newPosition >= size ? newPosition - size : newPosition;

            newArr[newPosition] = input.nextInt();

        }

        return newArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am thinking what the testcase looks like? Only one of them is not passing(TLE).

Comment: Or it is rather some sort of foolishness made by the question designer?

Comment: I doubt "which will directly output the scanner input up until the size of input has been met". Looks like you are still storing it in an array first. I.e. you have one write to array and one read from array unneeded. That is a relevant part of the time consumed.

Comment: The read from array can be omitted, that is there to verify the outcome of the transformation. I am not sure if the transformation can be directly outputted from the scanner as all the items recorded by the scanner need to be stored. 
I think the gist from the solution is that rather than storing all the items into an array and then transforming the array, the solution will directly store them into a transformed array.

Comment: Did you test this? I did and it gets confused by the first three values, number of testcases, size and rotation, which it treats as part of the sequence input.

Comment: The size and number of rotations are hard coded in this example and not treated as input parameters. I have updated the solution to take in the size and rotation as the first two inputs for single test case

Comment: Please check OPs definition of test input, there is a nother number which gets in the way, the number of test cases. Accepting them as inout is necessary (though I also then ignore it for simlification of the shown code...).